# How to join to jsons together

Tags: arrays, json

I have a question that is for me not easy to solute. I have a JSON output From a chat that I can not change, and I want to fill it in a other json 
blank. Is this possible and how

Chat-Output:

```
[{
    "username": "Support Team",
    "time": 1549182522,
    "text": "Hallo Willkommen"
}, {
    "username": "Support Team",
    "time": 1549182723,
    "text": "Hallo Willkommen"
}, {
    "username": "Support Team",
    "time": 1549185218,
    "text": "HHallo Willkommen"
}]
```

Other-Json:

```
{
    "id": "78",
    "json": ""
}
```

I need to fill the unable to change chat-output into the Other-Json in the json field. How could it work?

Comment: What do you mean by fill? What is your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? What is your programming language/platform? E.g. have you tried [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) ?

Comment: You mean that you want to put that chat JSON inside "json" object inside Other-JSON?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, so Other-Json:

> {
>       "id": "78",
>       "json": JSON.stringify(Chat-Output)
>   }